# How to authenticate to any mail provider using DotNetOpenAuth?

Tags: c#

I developed an ASP.net application that can send an email to any domain.
I'm using a simple .Net smtp client:

```
var fromAddress = new MailAddress("mymailid@gmail.com");
var fromPassword = "xxxxxx";
var toAddress = new MailAddress("yourmailid@yourdoamain.com");

var smtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",// or any others
        Port = 587, // correspond to host
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
    };
```

`smtpClient.Send(message)`. But I cannot authenticate to any modern mail providers(including gmail, yahoo, yandex) by using .Net.Mail because I have got the following exception `The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required`

All of the smtp configuration fill-out correctly.

How can I use DotNetOpenAuth for authentication and .Net.Smtp for sending emails?
Please give me an example.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: It is easier to help you if you post some sample code. Code that shows how you are posting it would help.

Comment: @KarlGjertsen updated the question

Comment: Thanks for the update.
Does Gmail allow you to use their SMTP server like that?
See my answer below, but I'd look at getting a free account with sendgrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I know I am adding a lot of answers, but here are my findings after looking at this for several hours:

`The error is the client is not authenticated (5.5.1)`

I got the same error, then I noticed an email in my inbox (the gmail account is seldom used) saying `Someone tried to sign in to your Google Account xxxxx@gmail.com from an app that doesn't meet modern securty standards.`

Is you app blocked by google: http://security.google.com/settings/security/activity might show your app, but are you getting an email?

Also, if the account uses 2 step authentication, the email will not be sent without setting an application specific password: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

I think this is account configuration instead of a problem with your code.

Comment: Yes, I have exactly the same message `Someone tried to sign in to your Google Account xxxxx@gmail.com from an app that doesn't meet modern securty standards.`

Comment: Gmail is blocking the request. There is nothing wrong with the code. SendGrid does not accept EnableSsl, which is why you got a slightly different error there.

Comment: So, my user should use 2 step authentication ?

Comment: Or as I asked in my question: I think that I can authenticate in my code by using http://dotnetopenauth.net/ and then I can use smtpClient to send messages? Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't think this is what OpenAuth is for. This is making sure Google (or any other provider) knows about the app. If this is something you are writing for other people to configure and use, they will need to make sure it is configured correctly. I think I misunderstood the question. Sorry I cannot be of more help.

Comment: So they should use 2 step authentication pass or allow less secure apps?

Comment: I believe this is the only way they can do it with gmail, yes.

Comment: Last question Karl, how can I ask my question more clearly? because you  misunderstood the question. Can you please re-formulate it?

Comment: I think the question is ok. I just read it first thing in the morning, before I had drank enough coffee!
Perhaps adding a short paragraph to explain about the email that is received in the inbox (from Google) when you try to send the email from the app.

Answer (score 4):

I'd consider your SMTP server. Is it allowing you to send email? Is your request making it to the server and being validated? Have you looked at the traffic using [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler)?

You can sign up for a free account with [SendGrid](http://www.sendgrid.com), who will provide you with a SMTP server to send the email for you. You really are better of using a company like SendGrid instead of the gmail SMTP server.

Other than that, [Mail4Net](http://www.mail4net.com) might help you in your code.

To use GMail as a SMTP Server, you have to set some values:

```
Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server: smtp.gmail.com
Use Authentication: Yes
Use Secure Connection: Yes (this can be TLS or SSL depending on your mail client)
Username: your GMail account, i.e. user@gmail.com
Password: your GMail password
Port: 465 or 587
```

You can also move your connection to the web or app config file:

```
<configuration>

  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="network" from="pam@gmail.com">
        <network
          host="smtp.gmail.com"
          port="465"
          enableSsl="true"
          userName="pam@gmail.com"
          password="password"
        />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>

</configuration>
```

Comment: So you think that I need to set `Use Authentication: Yes` ?

Comment: But `smtpClient` doesnt have such property

Comment: It is not a property, but you need to be authenticated, which you are. Have you tried using a different port number? Are your ports being blocked by your ISP?
You could try running Fiddler and seeing if the traffic is getting through or is being blocked: https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

Comment: Just download and tested. What should I see? I dont now how to work with Fiddler?

Comment: Run it and it will show you all of the traffic going out from your machine. Start the data capture, run the send code, stop the data capture and then look at the traffic. You should see your code calling the gmail server and any error will be shown in red.

Comment: I run a simple console app that send email and got the same error. Then open Fiddler and start  capturing (f12), then restart my simple app, got the error, stop capturing and don't see nothing...

Comment: I already check if 587 blocked by `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`. And saw that everything works fine

Comment: How about you try SendGrid. It only takes a few minutes and will tell us if it is an issue with the code or with the SMTP server.

Comment: Tried to move this to Chat, but I get a message saying the move has failed.

Comment: I use a browser to log in to my Google account and allow "less secure apps", and then everything works fine(my app work fine!). But I dont want to allow that.

Comment: Did you try the SendGrid approach?

Comment: yes, but I have my own class EmailSender that send emails and I want to use it

Comment: If I changed port to the 465 then I will get `System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection net_io_connectionclosed`

Comment: SendGrid is just a SMTP service, you will still need to use your own code.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Just tried and have exactly the same exception `System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection net_io_connectionclosed`

Comment: That's not the same error. Let me create a sample app from your code.

Comment: @KarlGjertsen I have changed `ivan_petrushenko` code `Host = "smtp.gmail.com"` to `smtp.sendgrid.net` and have the same exception.
If you have working code, please show your code.

Comment: I have a working sample, similar to your code above.
When you created the SendGrid account, did you update the credentials to be the correct username and password?
You are getting the password from your mail address, which could be incorrect!

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me, once the email and credentials are updated:

```
  try
  {

    var message = new MailMessage();

    message.Subject = "Test email";
    message.Body = "This is a test message";
    message.From = new MailAddress("from@email.com");
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("to@email.com"));

    var client = new SmtpClient
    {
      Host = "smtp.sendgrid.com",
      Port = 587,
      Credentials = new NetworkCredential("User_Name", "My_Password")
    };

    client.Send(message);

  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    var msg = ex.Message;
  }
```

Make sure your SendGrid credentials are correct.

Comment: Do you "allow less secure apps"? And what do you mean by "once the email and credentials are updated"? I have only one email and credential.

Comment: And what is "SendGrid credentials"? Do you mean credential that I use to login into my Gmail account?

Comment: Not allowing less secure apps.
You need to change the email addresses and the SendGrid credentials

Comment: My user should fill-out the following fields https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_ikyn0YIY7KazYwcFN4SllFaWc/view

Why they should create some account in SendGrid and use different pass?

Comment: Why do your users need to send the email from their account? What if they are not Gmail users?

Comment: OK, I see what you are trying to do now.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, I can see the [image](http://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_ikyn0YIY7KazYwcFN4SllFaWc/view), showing what you are trying to do:

However, you cannot know what the configurations are going to be and users will select configurations that are not correct. What will you do if the user selects TLS, but there is no TLS support from the mail server?

I think you need to add a Send Test Email button, to send a test email to check the configuration. You can then show any errors that are encountered.

Comment: If you remove EnableSsl from the code, does this work?

Comment: If I remove tls, then I will have `The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. b5sm867834lbc.14 - gsmtp`

Comment: As I said in my question .net.smtp. doesn't provide mechanism for the authentication

Comment: OK. What if the from email address is not the same as the SMTP server username? Or is this just an error in the code sample?

Comment: It does, that is what the `EnableSsl` flag is for. I am just not sure why it is not working.

Comment: I think because of that http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2014/04/new-security-measures-will-affect-older.html

Comment: I have exactly the same exception https://galleryserverpro.com/use-gmail-as-your-smtp-server-even-when-using-2-factor-authentication-2-step-verification/

but I also don't want to enable 2-step-verification